# Caching MKTileOverlay for offline use

Tags: caching, mkmapview, offline, mktileoverlay

I've got a MKMapView that loads a map from the following server with this format:

```
NSString *urlTemplate = @"http://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_gmaps?layers=topo2&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}";
```

And to cache the tiles loaded from this server, I know I have to save the tiles in the Documents folder of the app, but how?

And to render these tiles if present in Documents folder I know I have to subclass MKTileOverlay and make it check local storage before pulling from the server - but, again, how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

All the best - Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [MKTileOverlay's `loadTileAtPath` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKTileOverlay_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKTileOverlay/loadTileAtPath:result:), which allows you to load tiles from anywhere you want. You could implement a read through there.